# Terraform GPG key mismatch

Tags: security, terraform

I'm trying to install Terraform on Ubuntu with:

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/docker-get-started/install-cli

When trying to verify Hashicorp's GPG signing key I see this command

```
gpg --no-default-keyring \
    --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg \
    --fingerprint
```

should have the expected output of

```
/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg
-------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2020-05-07 [SC]
      E8A0 32E0 94D8 EB4E A189  D270 DA41 8C88 A321 9F7B
uid           [ unknown] HashiCorp Security (HashiCorp Package Signing) <security+packaging@hashicorp.com>
sub   rsa4096 2020-05-07 [E]
```

as of the posting of this question. This also matches [Hashicorp's Security page](https://www.hashicorp.com/security) under the heading `Linux Package Checksum Verification`.

However, I see a new key created 2023-01-10 instead:

```
/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg
-------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2023-01-10 [SC] [expires: 2028-01-09]
      798A EC65 4E5C 1542 8C8E  42EE AA16 FCBC A621 E701
uid           [ unknown] HashiCorp Security (HashiCorp Package Signing) <security+packaging@hashicorp.com>
sub   rsa4096 2023-01-10 [S] [expires: 2028-01-09]
```

Am I correct in not trusting this key, as until Hashicorp fixes their documentation, this could be a compromised key?

Comment: The incorrect GPG key is also listed at the official doc at https://www.hashicorp.com/official-packaging-guide. You may need to raise an issue about the documentation. The tutorial is probably triaged relative to the doc.

Comment: @MattSchuchard done https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/32565 we'll see...

Comment: Thanks for the report. Please follow https://status.hashicorp.com/incidents/5zxyf7fyzq91 for updates. The guides have been updated to reflect the new signing key fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

HashiCorp has rotated its main signing keys this week.

The updated key, along with a note confirming the change of key, is now in the [Official Packaging Guide](https://www.hashicorp.com/official-packaging-guide) document.